# Using left outer join for many-to-many relationship where null is allowed

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many table relationship in MySQL involving three tables: `tickets`, `ticket_solutions`, and `solutions`. (A ticket may have multiple solutions, and solutions apply to multiple tickets.)

Here are the table structures, simplified:

```
tickets    ticket_solutions    solutions
-----      -----               -----
id         ticket_id           id
           solution_id         solution
```

(In this example, all fields are `INT` except `solutions.solution` which is `VARCHAR`.) Since some tickets aren't completed, they may not have any solutions.

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sol.solution SEPARATOR ', ') solutions
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN ticket_solutions tsol ON (tsol.ticket_id = t.id)
LEFT JOIN solutions sol ON (tsol.solution_id = sol.id)
GROUP BY t.id DESC;
```

My question lies with the second `LEFT JOIN`. In any situation where an entry exists in the linker table (`ticket_solutions`) for a given ticket, there will *always* be a record to match in `solutions`. However if I try to use an `INNER JOIN` instead, I no longer get tickets which lack solutions.

To my thinking, the only time `NULL` values will occur is in the relationship between `tickets` and the linker table. (Ticket without any solutions yet.)

Must I use a `LEFT JOIN` between the linker table and `solutions` even though there won't be `NULL` values in that particular relationship?

If not, what is the recommended query structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sol.solution SEPARATOR ', ') solutions
    FROM tickets t
        LEFT JOIN ticket_solutions tsol 
            INNER JOIN solutions sol 
                ON (tsol.solution_id = sol.id)
            ON (tsol.ticket_id = t.id)
    GROUP BY t.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original SQL you left-join tickets to ticket_solutions, then inner-join the resulting view to solutions, which will supress rows without a corresponding solution.

In Joe Stefanelli's answer, which could also be written as

```
SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sol.solution SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ticket_solutions.ticket_id AS id, solutions.solution AS solution
     FROM ticket_solutions tsol 
     INNER JOIN solutions ON ticket_solutions.solution_id=solutions.id
    ) AS sol ON t.id=sol.id
```

you first inner-join ticket_solutions to solutions, then left-join the resulting view to tickets, thus NOT supressing the empty tickets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Joe Stefanelli is absolutely right.
Just wanted to add that you can use

```
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sol.solution SEPARATOR ', '), '')
```

to have an empty string instead of nulls.

However, since some other discussions about the same problem are confusing, just wanted to link this fiddle as well: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c6f/3/0